# 7zip file splitting "DVD" setting too big for a DVD

Tags: dvd, 7-zip, dvd-burning

I'm using 7Zip to split some large files so that I can copy them onto DVDs. I've done this before, using  7-zip's "Split to volumes" feature, and using the "DVD" size.

This is creating files that are 4,697,620,480 bytes (4.37Gb) in size, and when I attempt to copy them onto my DVD, I get a message saying that there isn't enough space on the disk. It says I need another 2.93Mb.

Last time I did this, I was using a different brand of blank DVDs. Could it be the disks themselves that are the problem? These are Verbatim DVD+R with "4.7Gb" written on them.

Aslo, what can I do now? The next-smallest setting in 7Zip is "CD" (650Mb).

Comment: You should be able to manually specify a split to volume size.

Comment: There's no option in the user interface to do so. Just a drop-down list of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply type a smaller value in the appropriate box - the drop-menu is just for suggested sizes, not the only available sizes.

It accepts sizes in bytes, K, M or G
eg 12345678 [bytes] 1234K or 12M etc

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DVD-R media holds approximately 6-7 additional megs of storage versus DVD+R media. Try using the DVD size option again but this time burn the files onto DVD-R media instead.

Comment: Assuming he has the right burner and appropriate disks lying around.